# logstash write sincedb file failed without any error

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

logstash 3.1.3, USE ELK to show the log files
when i try to config the logstash configuration, i meet a problem. the sincedb file never created.

```
input {
  file {
    debug => true
    discover_interval => 5 
    path => ["/var/log/iis-logs/ex*.log"]
    sincedb_path => "$HOME/sincedb.iis-logs"
    sincedb_write_interval => 15
    start_position => beginning
    stat_interval => 15 
    type => "test-iis-log"
  }
}
```

what's wrong with my config?
check the logstash log, no related information.

Comment: Try to use absolute path in sincedb_path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben's comment has the solution. As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/23df06e07e66bd9ba7ce854f7546ffc04a83589b/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb#L90-119), Logstash *does* check the environment variables `SINCEDB_DIR` and `HOME` if no path is given, but otherwise there is no variable expansion applied to the path.

The underlying FileWatch module [behaves similarly](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/41bdabf53ee1c1f4eda43b619d913c13bd21b8d5/lib/filewatch/tail.rb#L47-53).

`$HOME` should probably be replaced by an absolute path, probably `/home/yourusername` or some such, depending on your system. You could run `echo $HOME` on your command line to get an exact replacement.

Comment: from the code, means once i specified sincedb_path, logstash will not check "SINCEDB_DIR" or "HOME" staff. i donot get the point, sorry reply late.